# #ifdef and #define equivalent in Python (to switch between sorting by date and cost)?

Tags: python, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I have a class in Python:

```
class purchase:
    name: str
    day: int
    month: int
    year: int
    date: int #works by Julian Day Number
    cost: Decimal
```

I want to write a function to sort a list of objects of this class either by date or by cost, chosen by the user.

I can make 2 copy-pasted functions with only the sorting field replaced, but a much more elegant solution I would make in C++ is to use something like

```
#ifdef flag == 1

#define SORTING_FIELD cost

#else

#define SORTING_FIELD date
```

,and only have 1 function. Can I make something like this in Python?

Comment: Python comes withs its own sorted function, that receive a key parameter that is a function to sort the list by it. I guess you could do the same

Comment: You can use [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) for the sorting key.

Comment: So I should write a get_cost and get_date functions in my class, and do sorted(arr, key=arr[0].get_cost, reverse=True) for sorting by cost descending, for example?

Comment: Do something like `sorted(arr, key=operator.attrgetter(sorting_field))`.